# Append dynamic content from WP to Slick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, slick.js

So this is the deal: I have a slick carousel which loads different parts from a WordPress post on different slides. One of the slides holds a gallery (handmade query, no plugins.), which can grow a lot depending on how many items are queried inside it. My question is the following:

How can I slice gallery elements by 6 and add them as slides (I'm using `.slide` as the slide selector) on the parent slider, by batches of 6? More clearly, I need to *cut* them from inside the gallery slide, then wrap them by groups of 6 inside a `.slide` div and have them added by slick as slides. I've tried the following, both in jQuery & PHP:

**jQuery**

```
var divs = $('.gallery__item');


/* Option 1 - Slicing: doesn't work because it creates the slide div
   inside the parent slide div */

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=6) {
  divs.slice(i, i+6).wrapAll("<div class='slide'></div>");
}

/* Option 2 -  Slicing & Appending to rendered Slick Track: doesn't work
   since it doesn't actually append it because slick-track is script-generated
   when carousel is loaded */

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=6) {
  divs.slice(i, i+6).wrapAll("<div class='slide'></div>")
                    .appendTo("<div class='slick-track'></div>");
}


/* Option 3 - Index through each: doesn't work. Same error as 1 in any case. */

divs.each(function(i) {
  if (i % 6 == 0) {
    $(this).append('</div><div class="slide">');
  }
});
```

**PHP**

```
$i = 1;

<div class="slide">
  if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); [Example Query]


  if($i % 6 == 0) {echo '</div><div class="slide">';}

  $i++; endwhile; endif;

</div>
```

Slick itself has a [method](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) called `slickAdd`, but that isn't working either. :/ Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So here's a quick fix. If anyone has a better way, please feel free to comment.

```
var contSlider = $('.content-carousel'),
    divs = $('.gallery__item'),
    slides = [];


contSlider.slick({
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  arrows: false,
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  mobileFirst: true,
  slide: '.slide',
  slidesToShow: 1 });


if (divs.length > 6) { // If there are over 6 pics

  // Slice them in batches of 6
  for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=6) {
    var x = divs.slice(i, i+6);
    slides.push(x);

    // Remove elements from first slide
    if(i >= 6) {
      $(x).remove();
    }

  }

  // Iterate inside each batch of 6
  for( i = 1; i < slides.length; i++) {

    var y = [];

    // Iterate inside child HTML Object containing divs
    for(var j = 0; j < slides[i].length; j++) {
      // Push each element's outerHTML
      y.push(slides[i][j].outerHTML);
    }

    // Append to slider using Slick's slickAdd method
    contSlider.slick('slickAdd', "<div class='slide'>" + y + "</div>");

  }

}
```